# When using PostgreSQL 12.7 I can not make a basebackup due to the file length be limited, how can I get around this?

Tags: postgresql, backup

I am making a basebackup of a live system, the live system is on Ubuntu 20.04 on a ZFS filesystem and can not get the backup complete due a file length violation.

I have replaced the actual directory names with 'xxx' placeholders in this example

The command:

```shell
pg_basebackup -h xxx -p xxx -D /tank/xxx -U user \
 -F p -P -v -X stream -C -c fast -S xxx_slot
```

I tried to specify `-F p` for plain file format to avoid the following, but to no avail;

```shell
pg_basebackup: initiating base backup, waiting for checkpoint to complete
pg_basebackup: checkpoint completed
pg_basebackup: write-ahead log start point: 14CD/7C00BC38 on timeline 2
pg_basebackup: starting background WAL receiver
pg_basebackup: created replication slot "erc_qa"
1850117898/1850117898 kB (100%), 1/1 tablespace
pg_basebackup: error: could not get write-ahead log end position from server: ERROR:  file name too long for tar format: "xxxxxxxxx/ae6618ad18d8bf26cf757b121baafc928b85f068/xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxx-xx.svg"
pg_basebackup: removing data directory "/tank/xxxx"
```

Comment: I can't think of why there would be a file with that name in the first place.  I wonder if you have been hacked.

Comment: In addition to what @mustaccio has said, the file is a .svg (Scalable Vector Graphics) file and therefore unlikely to be included in a PostgreSQL backup!

Comment: I have just replaced the directory names with a placeholder